# Emacs and command line $PATH disagreements on OSX

Tags: osx, shell, path, haskell-mode

Having some issues with `PATH` settings on Emacs that are affecting my Haskell environment:

I'm using ZSH, and when I go to the command line and call `echo $PATH`, it returns: `/Users/g/Library/Haskell/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

This is coming from `.zprofile` configuration where I have:

```
# Set the list of directories that Zsh searches for programs.
path=(
  ~/Library/Haskell/bin
  /usr/local/{bin,sbin}
  $path
)
```

So, from command line, when I call `which cabal`, I correctly get: `/Users/g/Library/Haskell/bin/cabal`

When I start Emacs and go to the `shell` and call `which cabal`, I get: `/usr/bin/cabal` which is causing me issue since it's a different version.

When I inspect `echo $PATH` from the Emacs `shell`, I see: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/g/Library/Haskell/bin:/usr/local/sbin`

I've no idea how on earth the `PATH` can be different...

Anyone knows how to get my `ZSH` shell and Emacs to agree on the same `PATH`? I suspect that's what's controlling where `cabal` is being loaded from.

**UPDATE**: Running `echo $SHELL` from Emacs prints: `/bin/zsh`

**UPDATE 2**: This is on **OSX**.

**UPDATE 3**: I have tried to use [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) module and it does not work. I still have same issues, and as a side effect, it messes up my terminal theme colours :(

**UPDATE 4**: I've installed Emacs via `brew install --cocoa --srgb emacs` and I run emacs that's linked this way:

```
~ ❯❯❯ which emacs
/usr/local/bin/emacs
~ ❯❯❯ l /usr/local/bin/emacs
lrwxr-xr-x  1 g  admin    30B 29 Jan 18:34 /usr/local/bin/emacs -> ../Cellar/emacs/24.4/bin/emacs
~ ❯❯❯ l /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.4/bin/emacs
-r-xr-xr-x  1 g  admin    87B 29 Jan 18:34 /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.4/bin/emacs
```

Comment: Are you using ZSH as your login shell?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by login shell exactly, but I guess I called `chsh...` back in the day to change my default shell

Comment: I'm using iTerm2 btw...

Comment: Apparently not, modify PATH in `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile` then.

Comment: Set your environment variables in `~/.zshenv`, which will be consistently sourced however the shell is started (interactive vs. non-interactive). If `exec-path-from-shell` is messing up your terminal theme colours, you can set `exec-path-from-shell-arguments` to `nil` before calling `exec-path-from-shell-initialize` to make sure it's not running the interactive parts of your zsh config.

Comment: @sanityinc, adding PATH changes in ~/.zshenv is indeed a better solution. I figured it out when installing https://ghcformacosx.github.io

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an OSX annoying environment issue, the `$PATH` appearing in Emacs is coming from `/etc/paths` file, which then gets appended with whatever I've set in the shell. I added `/Users/g/Library/Haskell/bin` to the top of the `/etc/paths` file and it then worked fine.

Going into shell and calling `echo $PATH` in Emacs shows now: `/Users/g/Library/Haskell/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin`

And `cabal`'s version is indeed `cabal-install version 1.22.2.0` :D

Thanks all!!

Comment: Thanks to beOn for his hints in this `$PATH` on OSX [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832770/where-is-the-default-terminal-path-located-on-mac).

Comment: A better solution is to modify path in `~/.zshenv`. Changes there are reflected in Emacs' PATH

Comment: I can confirm that simply doing `echo export PATH=$PATH > ~/.zshenv` makes Emacs' `M-x shell` pick it up on the next invocation.

Comment: In 2020, OSX Mojave 10.14.6 doesn't appear to set the Mac Emacs path per the /etc/paths file.  A Mac Emacs subshell does seem to have run ~/.bashrc but not ~/.profile_bash, so you could set it in ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 27):

You can also install [exec-path-from-shell package](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) and add this to your init file:

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

Comment: The question would be better with a [link to the cited package](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

Comment: You're right, I've just edited my answer.

Comment: This is all I ever wanted.

Comment: This package is quite slow on macos, however... it noticeably slows down emacs startup.

Answer (score 6):

If you start emacs from your GUI environment (gnome, kde, ...) your shell startup scripts will not be sourced into your environment. So the `$PATH` that you carefully set in your `.zsh` will not be loaded. GUI environments do not generally source these, though they may load your `~/.profile` file.

You can try adding this to your `.pam_environment`:

`PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/MYHOMEDIR/Library/Haskell/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin`

You will need to restart your GUI session to load it.

This document might help you to get your `$PATH` variable set properly:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables

I use the `~/.pam_environment` file to managed environment variables that I need to be accessible from my shell or emacs processes.

PS: An astute commenter points out that you are probably on Mac. I don't know how to set up your `$PATH` in the Mac GUI, but the point still stands regarding the difference between your shell's environment and the GUI environment.  How you set up the `$PATH` for the GUI seems to depend on the OS version. However you can use:

`(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/foo/bar"))`

in your `~/.emacs.d/init` if you just want a solution that should work.

PPS: If you want to run a shell in emacs, you are probably better off using `ansi-term` rather than `shell`.

Comment: I doubt the question is about Linux given the questioner mentioned the use of [iTerm 2](http://iterm2.com/).

Comment: I must say this was a mystery for me. Thank you very much good person.

Answer (score 3):

If some part of the PATH gets lost then you can add it in your ~/.emacs

```
;;; We add /path/to/something/extra by appending it to the path
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/path/to/something/extra"))
;;; /path/to/something/extra is now at the end of the PATH.
;;; or you can use:
;(setenv "PATH" (concat "/path/to/something/extra:" (getenv "PATH")))
;;; /path/to/something/extra is now at the beginning of the PATH.
```

To avoid PATH issues, I always start emacs from the command line with the PATH exported from ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish this is to simply tell the shell that it's a login shell so that it sources all of the right files.   I do this for bash by setting `explicit-bash-args` to `("--noediting" "--login")`.  It looks like the equivalent for zsh would be to set `explicit-zsh-args` to `("-l")`.

So in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq explicit-bash-args '("--noediting" "--login"))
```

In yours, something like:

```
(setq explicit-zsh-args '("-l"))
```

I think the `"--noediting"` is unnecessary, and there doesn't seem to be a way to tell zsh about this, but that might be something to investigate if this doesn't work as well as you'd hope.

Comment: This works for a shell run under Emacs.  It does not work for commands run directly within Emacs, such as via `M-x shell-command`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set an OS X-wide default path by for example saving a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>launchctl setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The new path should be shown in shells, Emacs, and other applications after you log out and back in.

This method does not change the path in applications that are opened as login items or when applications are reopened at login after a forced shutdown. If you have Emacs, a terminal application, or other applications where you want to change the path in login items, you'll have to remove them.

In 10.9 and earlier you can also add a line like this to `/etc/launchd.conf`:

```
setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However support for `/etc/launchd.conf` was removed in 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

The given solutions didn't work for me. The reason is the latest Emacs compiled with `--with-native-compilation` picks up the PATH before loading `init.el` (to start compiling the packages with `gcc`).

This solution works if you put it into `early-init.el`.

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  "Set up Emacs' `exec-path' and PATH environment variable to match
that used by the user's shell.

This is particularly useful under Mac OS X and macOS, where GUI
apps are not started from a shell."
  (interactive)
  (let ((path-from-shell (replace-regexp-in-string
              "[ \t\n]*$" "" (shell-command-to-string
                      "$SHELL --login -c 'echo $PATH'"
                            ))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

(set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH)
```

Taken from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath.