# Org-mode latex pdf export command doesn't find citations

Tags: org-export, latex, org-mode, bibtex

I'm trying to write my thesis in org-mode, and so far it feels amazing. The integration with my todo system, the easy markup language, integration with latex. Wow.

But recently (since I upgraded to the latest latex version on my Arch system, and installed biber from the separate package) the export to pdf cannot find my references anymore.

If I export to .tex first and then run `latexmk -f -pdf minimal.tex` from the command line everything does work correctly.
Here are the relevant settings in my init file:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      (list "latexmk -f -pdf %f"))
```

Because it uses so many files, I made a small [git repo](https://github.com/japhir/minimallatex) with all the files.

- [minimal.org](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/japhir/minimallatex/master/minimal.org) is the source file. <sub>note that some of the lines start with `# +`, and are thus comments.</sub>
- [minimal.bib](https://github.com/japhir/minimallatex/blob/master/minimal.bib) is a tiny bibliography file.
- [minimal.tex](https://github.com/japhir/minimallatex/blob/master/minimal.tex) is the auto-generated .tex file.
- [fromlatexmk.pdf](https://github.com/japhir/minimallatex/blob/master/fromlatexmk.pdf) is the pdf file generated from the command line with the .tex file as input.
- [fromorgmode.pdf](https://github.com/japhir/minimallatex/blob/master/fromorgmode.pdf) is the pdf generated from org's `C-c C-e l p` (or `o`), with the failed references.

I hope somebody can help me solve this mystery!

Comment: I would recommend `org-ref`.

Comment: Shouldn't you add a -bibtex flag to latexmk?

Comment: @JohnKitchin latexmk was working correctly, but the command from emacs wasn't. In the end I made a small shells cript that calls the correct latexmk command and also performs some sed commands for cleanup.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. I have used this before and it worked fine. I need the shell-escape because of the minted package that is default for me.
(setq org-latex-pdf-process (list "latexmk -shell-escape -bibtex -f -pdf %f"))

Answer (score 2):

So a rather unsatisfying answer that works out, is to run the commands in from the command line to generate all the required auto files with `latexmk`. From then on the export commands from emacs work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a very long time to figure out. I had the same issue.

Specifically in macOS [the emacs shell does not properly inherit the PATH](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/emacs-and-command-line-path-disagreements-on-osx). In my situation, this meant that biber was not in path, but latexmk was. latexmk just builds the pdf anyway, with no viewable error message anywhere except ‘empty bibliography’ or ‘unknown citation’. There are many better solutions in the linked post, but here is my janky one solution:

```el
  (setq org-latex-pdf-process
    '("export PATH=\"/Library/TeX/texbin/:$PATH\";latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%o %f"))
```