# pdf export undefined citation, missing bibliography

Tags: org-export, org-ref

When I export with `org-latex-export-to-pdf`, the pdf does not contain the nicely-formatted list of references as expected, and the citation is just `[?]` instead of an actual link. It's just the single page as in the screenshot below. Org-mode's tooltip seems to understand the link:

[image]

However, when exporting I get this warning: `PDF file produced with warnings: [undefined citation]`.

How do I get a list of references at the end?

Here is my `simple.org`:

```
#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil toc:nil num:nil
this is a simple test with a citation cite:9422781.

bibliographystyle:unsrt
bibliography:simple.bib
```

Here is my `simple.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{9422781,
  author={Oleghe, Omogbai},
  journal={IEEE Access},
  title={Container Placement and Migration in Edge Computing: Concept and Scheduling Models},
  year={2021},
  volume={9},
  number={},
  pages={68028-68043},
  doi={10.1109/ACCESS.2021.3077550}}
```

Here is the `simple.tex` file produced:

```latex
% Created 2021-05-23 Sun 12:17
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{Firstname Lastname}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Firstname Lastname},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 27.1 (Org mode 9.5)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

this is a simple test with a citation \cite{9422781}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{simple}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get after exporting to pdf:

[image]

However, exporting to HTML seems to work (although I'd prefer something like `1` instead of the `9422781` link):

[image]

versions I'm using:

- org-mode 9.5
- emacs 27.1
- org-ref 1.1.1
- Mac OSX 10.14.6
- doom-emacs v2.0.9
- pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
- latexmk 4.69a

Comment: It could be that your setup is not running bibtex when making the pdf. See https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref.org#latex-export for hints.

Comment: I have tried both of those values for `org-latex-pdf-process`, and get the same undefined reference issue. Like [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/26220/10036), if I do the steps manually in the terminal (outside of emacs) it all works. But within emacs it does not.