# How to run python 3 in M-x shell?

Tags: python, osx

I am very new to emacs so it would be a big help if answers came with a lot of detail.

I've tried to get my `M-x shell` to run python 3 but can't. I've tried:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter 
      "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6")
```

and also adding this location to `~/.emacs` but neither have worked. I have python 3.6 installed and running in terminal but can't get it running in the `M-x shell`.  I'm using a mac.

Comment: `M-x shell` is for running a shell inside an emacs window.  Are you saying that in that shell, when you run `python` you get python2? An error? What error?

Comment: Yeah sorry. When I run python in that shell it uses python 2

Comment: Maybe setting PATH as in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10737/5296) would help?

Comment: Are you trying to get an interactive python REPL?  Or just want to run a python script?

Starting a shell from emacs and running python is a good way to do the latter, but Emacs has better ways to do the former

Comment: Since you've got python-shell-interpreter set, you can say `M-x run-python` to get to an interactive repl directly.  Down that rabbit hole you'll also learn how to send code directly from a python buffer to the repl, and other stuff that's useful for development

Answer (score 1):

`M-x shell` gives you an emacs buffer that mostly behaves as a regular shell terminal. That means that when you issue a command, like `find`, `grep` or `python`, it searches through your system path and runs the first program it finds that matches the name you used. The variable `python-shell-interpreter` has nothing to do with this.

Which means, on your system, the executable for `python` is pointing to python 2, not python 3. You'll have to fix this outside of emacs. Or you can explicitly set it within `M-x shell` if you want to make this a temporary change:

```
alias python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

You may prefer to directly alter the path.

You could also include code to modify your path, or set up an alias for python, in `.emacs.d/init_bash.sh`, which is applied every time you run `M-x shell`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run your script using `python3 script.py` too.